# CSS: Get button and a aligned

Tags: html, css

I am a little confused:
[image]

In the picture, the element that says "Navigation einblenden" is `span button`, while the one with "Suche" is a `span a`. I have styled them exactly the same:

part of the css, dispOpts is the class-name of the parent span. and the all:none is for testing.

```
.dispOpts {
    all:none;
}
.dispOpts button {
    all:none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}
.dispOpts a {
    all:none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
}
.dispOpts::before,
.dispOpts::after {
    display: none;
}
.dispOpts a:hover,
.dispOpts button:hover{
    background: var(--accent-color);
    color: white;
}
```

I cannot find any difference at all...
It is our workbench for a project at work:
http://exist3.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de:8080/exist/apps/edoc/view.html?id=e000001_kuttenberger_religionsfrieden_einleitung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your code, you didn't style them the same.

The `.dispOpts a` is missing `margin-bottom:2em;` and also to work the same as on button, you have to add also `display: inline-block` on `.dispOpts a`, and also to be same, they need to have same `line-height` and `font-size`, so result would be like this:

```
.dispOpts button {
    all:none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dispOpts a {
    all:none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And all would be lined correctly with same height.

Also you could use it with `all: initial;` and the end result would be:

```
.dispOpts button {
    all:initial;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}
.dispOpts a {
    all:initial;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0.4em;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

With this way, you would need only `margin-bottom`, and `display` on `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

Both link didn't have the same styles :

[image: Navigation link style] [image: Suche link style]

Comment: this is weird :-D 
after ```all:none; ``` I was sure it was the same :-D should have checked ... 
need to find a fix now